# Incorrectly updated innerHTML using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a basic typewriter with pure js.

I'm basically trying to emulate somebody typing with a keyboard in a believable fashion. Issue is, for some reason, my node's text doesn't seem to display and I can't seem to figure out why

```js
function get_random_in_interval(min, max){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

function typewriter(textinput){
  var min = 1;
  var max = 3;
  var rand = get_random_in_interval(min, max);
  var into = document.getElementById('textentry');


  for (i = 0; i < textinput.length; i++){
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if (i >= textinput.length){
          clearInterval(timer);
        }

        into.innerHTML += textinput.charAt(i);
      }, rand * 1000);
  }

}


 var test = "Hello, I am a <b>text</b> \n \n I tried doing some freaky stuff";
 typewriter(test);
```

```css
#textentry {
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="textentry"></div>
```

My best guess would be that I'm using `setInterval()` function incorrectly here. Issue is, I can't really think of where else should I place it. If i placed the `setInterval()` outside of `for()` loop, then it would work (tested it myself), but It would print the entire string at random intervals and not only the desired char.

Comment: Do you really want to set a new interval with every single loop iteration? Also, `i` will always equal `textinput.length` inside your interval function. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more simpler solution (compared to the other one):

This basically uses a `setInterval` and then stops after `i` becomes more than length.

```js
function get_random_in_interval(min, max){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

function typewriter(textinput){
  var min = 1;
  var max = 3;
  var rand = get_random_in_interval(min, max);
  var into = document.getElementById('textentry');
  var i = 0;
  let Htmlstring = ""; // Credit to Certain Performance for the idea

  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    Htmlstring += textinput.charAt(i);
    into.innerHTML = Htmlstring;
    i++;
    if (i > textinput.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, get_random_in_interval(min, max)*30);
  

}


 var test = "Hello, I am a <b>text</b> \n \nI tried doing some freaky stuff";
 typewriter(test);
```

```css
#textentry {
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<pre id="textentry"></pre>
```

Comment: You're only calculating `rand` once - every iteration will take exactly the same amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers here. I'm posting this just as an different alternative since there are a lot of ways to do this. You can use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` with a small recursive function.

```js
function get_random_in_interval(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

function typewriter(textinput){
    const min = 60;
    const max = 120;
    const into = document.getElementById('textentry');
    const type = (i) => {
        let rand = get_random_in_interval(min, max);
        setTimeout(() => {
            into.innerHTML = textinput.slice(0,i++)
            if (i < textinput.length) type(i)
        }, rand)
    }
    type(0)
}

var test = "Hello, I am a <b>text</b> \n \n I tried doing some freaky stuff";
typewriter(test);
```

```css
#textentry {
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="textentry"></div>
```

Comment: Good idea, but maybe update it so that the `<b>text</b>` works :)

Answer (score 1):

All the intervals are being set *synchronously*. By the time the `typewriter` function ends (before any intervals have run), `i` is equal to `textinput.length`, so `into.innerHTML += textinput.charAt(i);` doesn't work.

You also want to pause before each iteration - to do this, it would probably be easiest to `await` a `Promise` in the loop. (You definitely don't want `setInterval`)

```js
const get_random_in_interval = (min, max) => (
  new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min))
);

async function typewriter(textinput){
  var min = 5;
  var max = 45;
  var into = document.getElementById('textentry');
  let htmlStr = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < textinput.length; i++){
    await get_random_in_interval(min, max);
    htmlStr += textinput.charAt(i);
    into.innerHTML = htmlStr;
  }
}
 var test = "Hello, I am a <b>text</b> <br> <br> I tried doing some freaky stuff";
 typewriter(test);
```

```css
#textentry {
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="textentry"></div>
```

Replace the `\n`s with `<br>`s if you want to type HTML.

Comment: **Promises FTW!** ...although I'm curious, how would you solve this via the callback way (`typewriter('text', cb)`), without Promises.

Comment: Holy crap, that's awesome! First time I've seen `Promise` utilized like this. I'll try to study up on it tomorrow, to see if I can comprehend it better, optionally see if I have any questions to your implementation. As of now, it seems I've got some reading to do,

Comment: @RichardSzakacs Either with recursion (have the initial `typewriter` call some other function which has a `setTimeout` and recursively calls itself) or by calculating all increments ahead of time and calling every `setTimeout` at once

Comment: Should be an easy fix though.

Comment: @CertainPerformance awesome, you just gave me my morning coding exercise for the coffee. **Thanks!**